# Lights in A-Frame have striped artifacts depending on distance from them

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, aframe, virtual-reality

I am using the latest A-Frame 1.0.4 and I have tried both with spot light (in the picture attached) and with direct light.

The shadowBias is set to -0.0001, changing it affects the artifact only slightly.

If I set the shadowMapHeight and shadowMapWidth to 1024 the artifact shrinks back a bit from the source of light. To have it completely disappear I have to put 4096, which is a bit too much, performance-wise. I can't have all lights with a 4k shadow map.

A similar effect has increasing the shadowCamera far, from 500 to 5000 for example. but this introduces wrong shadows, distant from the objects (even if I tweak the shadowBias).

Am I doing something wrong? Why the lights with default settings have these problems? Does it perhaps depend on the models ?

Any clue would be appreciated

[image: artifact]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find the culprit! My models are double sided, and this resulted into the front face casting shadow on the back face together with the back face casting shadow on the front face, hence the striped glitch.

After having a look at [three.js - material](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/Material) and confirming with `material.side` that it was actually double sided, I used `material.shadowSide = THREE.BackSide` to force the backside to cast shadow onto the frontside, regardless of the model/material double side property.
This solved the glitch!

Of course be mindful that if a model has wrong normals i.e. don't facing towards the outside / inverted , that face will have the glitch again.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded a fairly complex, animated model ([this one](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/medieval-fantasy-book-06d5a80a04fc4c5ab552759e9a97d91a)) as glTF from Sketchfab and manged to get the shadows right(-ish) with these parameters:

```
<a-entity shadow="cast: true; receive: true" id="model1" gltf-model="scene.gltf"
  position="6 1.5 -12" scale="0.5 0.5 0.5" animation-mixer>
</a-entity>

<a-entity light="type: ambient; intensity:0.1;"></a-entity>

<a-entity id="sun" light="type: directional; color: #FFF; intensity: 0.9; castShadow: true; shadowCameraFar: 500;
    shadowCameraVisible: false;
    shadowBias: -0.001;
    shadowMapHeight:2048; shadowMapWidth:2048;
    shadowCameraLeft: -50; shadowCameraRight: 50;
    shadowCameraBottom: -50; shadowCameraTop: 50;" position="10 50 -10">
</a-entity>
```

The result looked good:
[image: result]
but you can still see some artefacts. Additionally it was just a tad too much stress for the Oculus Quest.

Overall, I (re)turned to shadow baking for my own models which of course doesn't help with animated models.

I do remember that I had one model that showed this effect due to z-buffer fighting, not the shadows.

So maybe you start with this model, adjust the parameters accordingly, find the same results as me, and then you throw your model in there.

Maybe this helps.

Comment: thanks for you help! i was able to find the problem. my models are double sided, which results in `material.side === THREE.DoubleSide` and since `material.shadowSide === null` by default, both front and back face will cast shadow onto eachother, hence the glitch.